# Mixed integration problem

Tags: integration

Well I am quite embarrassed asking this as I have done really advanced stuff in college but its been awhile and I have completely forgotten how to do it, since I don't do Math in university (in UK college is a compulsory extension of high school, sort of).

We have: $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \dfrac{5}{y^2}$ Find: $dy/dx$

I think we need to rearrange the equation. It would be easy if on the right side we would've x, but it's y, hence the rearrangement is required.

I did something like this, but I doubt its correct:

Rearrange: $y^2 * d^2y = 5 * dx^2$

Integrate both sides: $\dfrac{y^3}{3} * dy = 5x * dx$

Rearrange back into required form: $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{3*5x}{y^3} + c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{5}{y^2}$$

Now, $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

by definition.

Substitute, $t=\frac{dy}{dx}$

$$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{5}{y^2}$$

$$t\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{5}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$t\,dt = 5\frac{dy}{y^2}$$

On integrating,

$$\frac{t^2}{2}+C = -\frac{5}{y}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{C - \frac{10}{y}}$$

Comment: Thank You, I understood this completely. Thanks a lot for the amazing explanation.

Comment: @user138195 you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

One standard way to solve a problem like this is to multiply both sides of the equation by $dy/dx$ and pull out a $d/dx$, which gives
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{5}{y^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} \\
\implies \frac{d}{dx}\Big[\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2\Big]&=\frac{d}{dx}\Big[-\frac{5}{y}\Big]
\end{align}
(Do you understand the trick here?)
It follows upon integrating with respect to $x$ that
\begin{align}
\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2 &= -\frac{10}{y} + C \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \sqrt{C-\frac{10}{y}}.
\end{align}

Comment: very nice trick

Comment: I can't figure out what happened on the left side. On the right side it looks like you differentiated it to respect with y, but don't understand what you did on the left side to get 1/2. Sorry for my incompetence, could you please explain that part?

Comment: @user138195 read my answer. it is essentially the same, it makes the step more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be using a technique you learnt at school.

Multiply the equation by $dy/dx$:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{5}{y^2} \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Then notice the left hand side is half the derivative of $(dy/dx)^2$, so integrate with respect to x:

$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = \int \frac{5}{y^2} \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int \frac{5}{y^2} dy = c - \frac{5}{y}$$

So

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{c-\frac{10}{y}}$$